# what causes CRVAP0237E error, how to fix it?

Tags: clearcase

I got an Error saying:

```
An error occurred during a clearcase operation"
```

Then:

```
CRVAP0237E Resource 'cc.repo.cc-activity:1225576@bd0e4b228d5e4e24b0e5a5a785af21': 
not found
```

Do you have any clue as the source of those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `CRVAP0237E` error code is usually associated with ClearQuest (like in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21373108) for instance).
So if your UCM project has also a ClearQuest link activated, that can be a lead.

It is also found for ClearCase when a resource has been renamed: [technote swg1PM11476](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM11476).
That means, it depends on your exact ClearCase version (since that particular bug has since then been fixed).

The fact that ClearCase refers to the activity by mentioning the *id* of the PVob (`bd0e4b228d5e4e24b0e5a5a785af21`), instead of the *name* of the PVob leads me to think that PVob is no longer available in your current environment, possibly because **its name (tag) is no longer referenced in your current ClearCase region**.

You need to check if `bd0e4b228d5e4e24b0e5a5a785af21` still matches one the the (p)vobs listed in `<ClearCase server>/rgy/vob_object` and `<ClearCase server>/rgy/vob_tag`.

You also need to mention the exact ClearCase operation you were doing when this error occurs (checkout? deliver? rebase?).

Comment: checkout was the operation thanbsk for replying!

Comment: @GoBucks so try setting another activity: `cleartool setact aNewActivity@\yourPVob` before trying your checkout again.